# What does having negative position mean in Java?

Tags: java

As a newbie in Java, I have always wondered what is meant by this fourth line of code.

```
String[] Songs = new String[10];
int position;
.....

if(position != -1)
```

What does it mean for a position in an array to be -1 in java, I know in python values such as -1 could be helpful in reversing tuples.

Comment: Perhaps the -1 is a sentinel value check? -1 as an array position in Java is invalid.

Comment: You need to ask a clearer question. What you've shown us won't compile as `position` is not initialised.

Comment: Lets say that you are iterating array from last element to first one, and you are doing it by decreasing value of current `position` from `length-1` till `0` (including `0`). So for which first value of `position` you should stop your loop?

Comment: That's exactly my thinking. String methods that search for string contents return -1 if it is not contained, so I always figured -1 was just a default DNE value.

Comment: Position is just an int.  It can be any value positive or negative.  The code you posted does not set the value of position to anything then tests to see if it's -1.  That doesn't make any sense at least with just the code you posted.  If you used position to index into an array and it's value was -1 you'd get an exception saying index out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your example the position isn't being applied to the array. so the program is simply checking if position is not -1.

If you try to access Songs[-1] you'd get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.